# How can I equalise intensity for a set of images?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have hand-drawn a set of square tiles, over a period of time.
They are essentially black ink on while paper.

After scanning in, and sizing, I wrote some code to construct larger images from the tiles.

However, i can see that they don't all have the same intensity of black and white, and in the resulting big image, I can see certain tile jump out.
I want to reduce this effect.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about this project?  What specific steps have you taken to get from paper to the final image and what tools did you use to perform them?  Do you need a program that evaluates the image, finds the outliers and corrects them or do you plan to tweak it by eye?  If the former, have you identified a criterion that would tag sub-images needing adjustment?  This might be a cool problem, but I think that it needs some elaboration.

Comment: Mike, thanks for asking for more detail.   i used white paper with green grid lines.   After drawing, I scanned in and then used Photoshop to remove the green.  It's probably this step which has resulted in the differences.   The tiles were done over months, and the paper may have changed.

Comment: Matt something that I should have asked earlier, what image formats are you using, for the sub-images and your final result? Have you reduced the images to 1 bit to eliminate all color information.

Comment: They are 8 bit RGB jpg tiles, and I'm not fussy about final image.  My goal is to make a large print.   Converting them to greyscale and smoothing has helped a bit.  here's an example. http://imgur.com/D2NzjO0

Comment: Mike's suggestion is then indeed the best: reduce the color information to a binary scale. You'll end up with a binary image (black&white), which will have the correct (or easily rescalable) intensities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this to be a particularly intriguing problem.  However, it has been clumsily posed, so I've suggested that Matt improve the question with some edits.  Meanwhile, a few observations.

My first thoughts were that perhaps the mismatch was a result of residual color differences in the sub-images, hence my suggestion in the comments to eliminate subtle shades by converting to a 1 bit format.  Matt subsequently shared the image, which gave me an opportunity to see the problem rather than merely speculate on it.  Here's his mosaic image (scaled to 10% of the original size):

[image: Matt's image, reduced]

To my eye the visual inconsistency between the tiles of the mosaic is a result of line width and weight variation between the sub-images more so than any "color" variations.  This variation makes the problem more difficult (to me at least) and of course more interesting.

I tried a few things with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) just to see if I could get a handle on this issue.  (Yes Matt requested PIL in the solution, but ImageMagick is great for rapid prototyping of imaging solutions.)  I found that sharpening and blurring had no significant effect, at least for the parameters I explored.  Contrary to my intuition, contrast reduction was helpful, but is did turn the background gray.  I compensated for this background shift by applying a white threshold.

```
$ convert D2NzjO0.jpg -brightness-contrast -75% -white-threshold 10% proc.jpg
```

I think that this processing did improve the image

[image: contrast processed image]

Obviously the line weight effects have not been eliminated by this processing.  It does look as if the too light strokes have been moderated, but the extra heavy strokes still stand out.  Perhaps other parameters of this contrast and threshold processing will yield better results.  I'll leave that as an exercise to Matt if he finds the approach promising.

Perhaps a better approach would be some sort of stroke detection and normalization process.  That sort of processing is well beyond my knowledge, so I can do no more than speculate on that.  If the question is **significantly** improved, it may be worthwhile to add [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) and/or [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) tags.  Matt feel free to riff off of my comments and answer should you decide to create a better question.  If you borrow heavily, I'd appreciate some attribution.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your comments, especially you candid feedback about my question.   Asking questions in ways people can answer helpfully is a skill i want to develop.   The image I uploaded was actually much smaller than the version I originally looked at.  I had a 30x30 mosaic, and zoomed out the barker tiles were more obvious.   Converting to greyscale has help a lot.   I will try your suggestions.

Comment: @Matt I'm happy that you appreciate my contributions on this question. I hope that you get good results on this challenging problem.